# Putting washer dryer hookups through nearby interior wall

Tags: drywall, dryer, clothes-washer

I recently purchased a home and will soon be putting in a washer and dryer (both electric).

The current hookups are in a small bathroom, but only a couple feet away is an interior wall, which on the other side would be the perfect placement for the washer and dryer. I really don't want to put the washer and dryer in the bathroom as the space is already cramped.

I can easily just put a hole in the wall and I believe all the connections will easily go through and I'll have enough slack in the cords.

My concern is the following:

1. How can I do this safely? (there is an electrical outlet within a foot of where I'll put the hole.)
2. How can I make the hole aesthetically pleasing?
3. How can I make it so the occupant doesn't have to worry any more than usual about sound traveling through the hole
4. How can I make it so that the occupant doesn't have to worry about someone being able to see in?

Comment: Maybe post a picture of the space?

Comment: to cover a hole in sheetrock I usually use a paint stir stick or 2 , using sheet rock screws bridge the hole on each side, use caution when tighting the screw so you dont split the stir stick, (you can use something stronger. after my paint stir sticks are in place i cut a piece of sheetrock to fit the hole , a couple of screws in each stick through the sheetrock to hold it in place. Then fill the crack with taping compound, or spackle. last after the crack mud is dry put a thin layer of tape compound on the rock  ~ 1-1/2' ether side of the hole seal with spark gapped tape and work out bubbles

Answer (score 1):

#### NO!

SJ Cord ( That cord that the dryer and washer whips are made from ) is not permitted to pass through the interior of a finished wall.

Comment: if the hole is finished off and large enough to easily pass the cord through, would there by any issue with this?